# How to call multiple methods of multiple objects

Tags: racket

Supposed I have a class:

```
(class object%
  (init val)
  (define/public (get-val) ... )
  (define/public (get-norm) ... ))
```

Why if I have two instances `foo` and `bar` i can do so:

```
(eval '(send foo get-val))
```

but can't do so:

```
(for/list ([who  '(foo bar)])
  (for/list ([what '(get-val get-norm)])
    (eval (cons 'send (list who what)))))
```

In the latter case I get the error:

```
send: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: send
```

What is the good way to get the result I want?

**UPDATE:** I have discovered that the nested loop works fine in the interactive mode, but produces the error if written in the definition area. Could anyone please explain what's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(for*/list ([who (list foo bar)]
            [what '(get-val get-norm)])
  (dynamic-send who what))
```

The reason for that is that `'(foo bar)` is a list containing two symbols, `foo` and `bar`, and *not* a list containing the values of the variables `foo` and `bar`; you have to use `(list foo bar)` for that.

Also, in order to be able to `send` to a method name that's in a variable, as opposed to naming the method directly, you have to use `dynamic-send` instead.

Notice that my code does not use `eval`, and neither should you. Most of the time, you never need to use `eval`, and it's best avoided whenever possible.

Comment: But then why I could use my version of the loop? And what exactly did the environment try to convey to me by the error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of `eval`. Using `eval` in the REPL works just fine because the REPL provides a namespace to `eval` with all the exports of `racket`. The REPL essentially works by first running the module then creating a new namespace with all the resulting definitions and calling `eval` on anything you enter using that namespace, so `send` is defined when you call `eval`. However, in the definitions window, you need to provide a namespace to `eval` yourself for this to work properly because the *initial current namespace* is empty. So what you could do is add this to the beginning of your definitions:

```
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
```

Now whenever you use `eval`, pass in `ns` as the namespace argument as in `(eval '(+ 1 2)` ns). There's a number of caveats however.

1. This is a *seperate namespace*. Anything you've defined in your module won't be visible in anything evaluated with this namespace. If you `(define foo 3)`, `(eval '(+ 1 foo) ns)` won't work - `foo` isn't defined in the `ns` namespace, it's defined in your current module namespace.
2. This namespace only imports `racket/base` by default. You'll have to do some eval-shenanigans or some namespace-shenanigans to require `racket/class`.
3. You could pass eval the value of the `(current-namespace)` parameter, but this comes with it's own special blend of caveats and complexity.
4. Communicating between namespaces is *not fun*. That's usually what modules are for.

The central problem is that `eval` is very, very, very rarely an appropriate tool for a job, let alone the best tool. There are a lot of corner cases and gotchas that can creep up on you without you having any idea what happened, not to mention the performance problems that can fester. Avoid it like the plague unless you really know what you're doing and are confident there's no better alternative.

May I ask why exactly `foo` and `bar` need to be processed using `eval` in your problem?

### EDIT

More information on `eval` can be found in [the Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html), which is extremely thorough and a useful resource.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I was playing with methods which return class definitions and therefore tried to view how instances of created classes behave. It seemed to me too much work to write the same calls for large set of objects. So I decided to apply the procedures to the objects in a loop. So far, purely for testing/debugging.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you happen to know that you need to call the same method on list of objects (that are all assumed to implement an interface or derive from a class defining the method), then you can use Racket's `map` function and an anonymous function to do this without needing a loop: `(map (lambda (obj) (send obj get-val)) objects)`